# How can I registers jQuery assets inside head tag?

Tags: jquery, yii, yii2

Well I am not familiar with Yii2 asset bundles. Yii2 asset bundle registers css files on the top of the page and js files on the bottom of the page. But How can I include those js files too on the top of the page?

```
class AppAsset extends \yii\web\AssetBundle
{
    public $basePath = '@webroot';
    public $baseUrl = '@web';
    public $depends = [
        'yii\web\YiiAsset',
        'yii\bootstrap\BootstrapAsset',
    ];
}
```

I just need all the js and css file to be registered on the top of the page. Using `AppAsset`, Is it posible?

**EDIT**

default registered scripts

```
<head>
....
<link href="/assets/4850c11c/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
....
</head>
<body>
.....
<script src="/assets/76016e7c/jquery.js"></script>
.....
</body>
```

I just need

```
<head>
....
<link href="/assets/4850c11c/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="/assets/76016e7c/jquery.js"></script>
....
</head>
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Just add one line to your bundle class.

```
public $jsOptions = ['position' => \yii\web\View::POS_HEAD];
```

Your code will look like this then:

```
class AppAsset extends \yii\web\AssetBundle
{
    public $basePath = '@webroot';
    public $baseUrl = '@web';
    public $jsOptions = ['position' => \yii\web\View::POS_HEAD];

    public $depends = [
        'yii\web\YiiAsset',
        'yii\bootstrap\BootstrapAsset',
    ];

    public $js = [
        'somefile.js'
    ];
}
```

Alternatively, you can also specify just the files you want in header section using a config array instead of string (Warning: The first element must be the filename).

```
class AppAsset extends \yii\web\AssetBundle
{
    public $basePath = '@webroot';
    public $baseUrl = '@web';

    public $depends = [
        'yii\web\YiiAsset',
        'yii\bootstrap\BootstrapAsset',
    ];

    public $js = [
        'this_file_will_be_at_end.js', // The default position
        ['but_this_will_be_at_header.js', 'position' => \yii\web\View::POS_HEAD],
        ['and_this_too.js', 'position' => \yii\web\View::POS_HEAD]
    ];
}
```

Answer (score 5):

To include a JavaScript file in the head section of a page (by default, JavaScript files are included at the end of the body section), use the following option:

```
 public $jsOptions = ['position' => \yii\web\View::POS_HEAD];
```

or  directly in view

```
 $this->registerJs('js/myjsfile.js', $this::POS_HEAD);
```

You can see http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-output-client-scripts.html

http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-structure-assets.html

Comment: His AppAsset file also need some improvement like include js and css in AppAsset too.

Comment: He can add ref to the files  directly in the head section  or (like Yii2 suggested) add the required Asset in  a proper asset ..  .PS . the asset in OP question  are the default Yii2 assests and are load by default in normal yii2 app